# Acquia cloud installing a module: private key file

Tags: 8, acquia-dev-desktop, acquia-cloud, ssh

I'm currently building a CMS using Drupal 8 hosted in [Acquia Cloud](https://www.acquia.com/).
At this time of the process, the goal was to do the setup of URL Patterns.

In order to do this, I need to install the module [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) and its requirements ([Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) and [CTools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools)) [[as it's shown here](https://youtu.be/9SvNuhk4ZUA?list=PLtaXuX0nEZk9MKY_ClWcPkGtOEGyLTyCO)].

After some going around, found out the installation of modules isn't actually as straightforward as clicking a button, inferred from seeing the following screen (doesn't appear that functionality).
[image: acquia_drupal_extend]
After some research, found that [there's a page in Acquia documentation with an explanation of how to install a Drupal module on Acquia Cloud](https://docs.acquia.com/acquia-cloud/develop/install-module).

The approache I started doing was to develop the application locally using [Acquia Dev Desktop](https://www.acquia.com/products-services/dev-desktop), add new modules using local tools like [Drush](http://www.drush.org) or the Update Manager, and then push the code to Acquia Cloud with Acquia Dev Desktop.

After installing Acquia Dev Desktop, I need to do the login using the Acquia Cloud credentials.
[image: acquia_drupal_login]

While on it, there's a button meant to allow to clone this site locally, which is what I want to do now.
[image: button]

After filling up all the details (sanitizing the database),
[image]

I'm asked to provide a private key:
[image]

In order to get that key, Acquia allows to generate automatically a public key (using the button "Generate" in this last image)
[image]

Once the public key was generated, to complete the process I'm redirected to [this link](https://docs.acquia.com/acquia-cloud/ssh/enable/add-key). Following it I was able to generate the SSH key which appears under

> /app/profile/ssh-keys
>    on my Acquia Cloud account.

After this, *I'm in need of a Private key file to continue the process and i'm blocked*.
Given this information bellow, **what can I do to have it**?

Attentively

Tiago

Comment: Click “Save key pair” in the 6th screenshot? That will surely let you download both public and private key files. If not, check ~/.ssh/, that’s typically where keys get generated

Comment: Saving like that I get a .pub file... :s AND, if I force it to be .ppk, then will give an error "SSH authentication failed. Please provide another key."

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use either Drush or Composer locally and commit the update. The UI installer is a mess on basically any host.

Comment: I'm really unsatisfied with this Acquia Cloud... complicating what should be straightforward...

Comment: It’s not Acquia Cloud. You started using a host that just has cPanel installed, arguably worse. You’ll have other problems later from this, unrelated to Drupal.

Comment: Technically I can say that because of the dependency on Acquia Dev Desktop while installing a module. About the cPanel, why is that worst? Tell me one of those problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to **forget about Acquia and start using cPanel.**

In here, was as straightforward as creating a subdomain, taking advantage of [Softaculous](https://www.softaculous.com) scripts by installing in that location the 8.4.3 version of Drupal.

Once installation was complete (which was a matter of seconds) and I've logged in as admin, **installing a module was never easier**!

See for yourself:
[image]

Tiago

Comment: I'm able to install the module like this which was my objective. So, this solution can be considered correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key you generated from Acquia Dev Desktop by following these additional steps (I was in a similar situation and this resolved for me):

1. Log into https://cloud.acquia.com
2. Open "Account Settings" (click account icon in the upper right corner, then click Account Settings)
3. Click "SSH Keys" on the navigation menu on top.
4. On the SSH Keys screen, you can add new keys by clicking "Add SSH Keys"
   in the upper right corner.
5. Add the public key that you want on your account (info from key generated by Acquia Dev Desktop).

After adding your public key to your Acquia account, you should be able to use the key from Acquia Dev Desktop.